# Setting a return carriage after character count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a formula that pulls in data from an external spreadsheet. Often times the content spills out of the print area.

How can I take this formula and perform a carriage return after x number of characters?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, IMPORTRANGE("source", "B2:C"), 2, 0))
```

Comment: Something like after x number of characters do "Char(10)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how you perform split after each 5 characters:

```
 =JOIN(CHAR(10), SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1), "(.{5})", "/$1"), "/"))
```

[image: 0]

therefore, try something like this:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, IMPORTRANGE("source", "B2:C"), 2, 0))), 
 "(.{50})", "/$1"), "/"))
```

Comment: For reference (anyone else searching for solutions), I was able to force end user to include a comma to separate the order input, then a formula breaks out everything with a comma and trailing space into a new carriage return. =regexreplace(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1, IMPORTRANGE("source", "B2:C"), 2, 0)), ", ", char(10))